# Prove if P(A|C) > P(B|C) and P(A|C') > P(B|C') then P(A) > P(B).

Tags: probability, inequality

Prove that if under two conditions that together have probability 1 ($C$ and $C'$), probability of $A$ is greater than probability of $B$, then $P(A) > P(B)$ in general.

Comment: Do you understand what you ask?

Comment: Use the [total probability rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalProbabilityTheorem.html) and it comes out in two steps.  If you are still having trouble, post your working and explain where you are stuck, then someone may be able to help further.

Comment: Do you have to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion? I'm unsure what the total is that these parts have to sum to. I'm trying to express it as the sum of intersections: (C ∩ (A U B)) U (C' ∩ (A U B)) = (A ∩ C) U (A ∩ C') U (B ∩ C) U (B ∩ C'). I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: No you do not use the PIE at all. Use the LOTP as David suggested.

Comment: I tried letting the area designated by (A ∩ C) U (A ∩ C') U (B ∩ C) U (B ∩ C') be called E. Then I took probabilities of the portions of E using the LOTP:

P(E) = P(A ∩ C) + P(A ∩ C') + P(B∩C) + P(B∩C') 
P(E) = P(A|C)P(C) + P(A|C')P(C') + P(B|C)P(C) + P(B|C')P(C') 
P(E) = P(C)(P(A|C) + P(B|C)) + P(C')(P(A|C') + P(B|C')). 

From here I'm stuck again, since I'm not sure how to relate this to an inequality showing P(A) > P(B).

Comment: I apologize for the lack of new lines; I tried hitting enter and it didn't produce the desired spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LOTP says that 
$$P(A) = P(A|C) P(C) + P(A|C^\prime)P(C^\prime)$$
and
$$P(B) = P(B|C) P(C) + P(B|C^\prime)P(C^\prime)$$

Since $P(A|C) - P(B|C) >0$ and $P(A|C^\prime) - P(B|C^\prime) >0$, we have
$$P(A)-P(B) = \left[ P(A|C) - P(B|C) \right] P(C) +[ P(A|C^\prime) - P(B|C^\prime) ] P(C^\prime) > 0$$